# BLE-Adv HCI_Script

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I've been writing a BLE Advertisement Script using HCI Tester but encountered the following error in the script:

> ERROR - packet Size. Got: 9 (0x09), Expected: 10 (0x0a)

[image]

I am using CC2640R2 development board. What could be the possible solution for this error?

I looked out for the parameters in TI documentation and tried to modify them but got no luck!